# Allow internet access for ffmpeg in android

Tags: android, permissions, ffmpeg

I have compiled a ffmpeg binary for android, now I am trying record hls stream with it. For this, I am using Runtime.exec() commands. 
This is the command I am passing to binary:

```
./ffmpeg -i VIDEO_URL -c copy -bsf:A aac_adtstoasc OUTPUT.mp4
```

However, when I run this command I see "Cannot resolve host" error for any given url. My app has internet and access network state permissions, But I think that since ffmpeg binary is another process, android does not grant it with same permissions as my app.

So my question is that, how can I give the binary Internet permission without root access.

If this is not possible, can you guide me what other ways I can do to download a hls stream?

Thanks

Comment: did u get the solution for this

Comment: Unfortunately I could not. Cannot grant internet permission to the binary.

Comment: I want to give camera permission. See this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35986159/unable-to-access-device-camera-using-ffmpeg-permission-error. Do you have any idea how to solve this? Are there any alternative solutions