# Unable to access device camera using ffmpeg: Permission error

Tags: android, ffmpeg

I am using a FFMPEG java wrapper for Android through which I am able to run any ffmpeg commands.

I have given my Android application the camera permission and the write external storage permission but ffmpeg is not able to access the device camera.

I am getting the following error when I run the command

```
  ffmpeg -re -f fbdev -r 10 -i /dev/graphics/fb0 -c copy -f flv rtmp://192.168.1.35:1935/app2/myStream 

  Error:     Could not open framebuffer device '/dev/graphics/fb0': Permission denied
```

How do I provide ffmpeg with camera access permission. I have tried giving `chmod 777 /dev/graphics/fb0` but that does not work.

Can someone tell me a solution for this?

Comment: Root the device, then run that command as superuser. I don't think `/dev/graphics/fb0` is accessible any other way.

Comment: ok. just to confirm, does  that means anyone who actually streams a camera feed using a java wrapper for ffmpeg does it on a rooted device only?

Comment: Either that, or they are not using `ffmpeg`, but instead are using `MediaRecorder` or similar stuff from the Android SDK.

Comment: I believe that camera is `/dev/video0`, at least on some devices. But even then it won't work without root access.